# Botão adicionar não diferencia produtos

Tags: javascript, html

Sou iniciante em HTML e JavaScript e estou travado num problema para um projeto da faculdade. Basicamente eu tenho um e-commerce sem BD, então os produtos estão definidos no HTML.

Meu problema é que ao clicar no botão adicionar ao carrinho, ele não diferencia os produtos e acaba adicionando só o primeiro produto.

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Essa class row que é a linha que eu falei-->  
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="Fonte">
            <fieldset>
            <legend class="prod">Fonte Corsair 400w</legend>
                 <img src="imagens/Fonte/fonte-corsair-vs400-80plus-white-pfc-ativo-400w-cp-9020117-la-1502453690.jpg" id="foto">
            <p>R$: </p><p input type="number" id="txtValor">229.90</p>
            <p>
                Quantidade<br>
                <input type="number" id="txtQtde" min="1" max="5" oninput="calcTotal();">
            </p>
            <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                Adicionar
               <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button> 
        </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="pv1060">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="prod">GTX 1060 3GB</legend>
                 <img src="imagens/Placa_de_video/placa-de-video-geforce-galax-gtx-1060-oc-3gb-60nnh7dsl9c3-gddr5-pci-exp_33631.jpg" id="foto">
            <p id="txtValor">
               R$ 1349,90
            </p>
            <p>
                Quantidade<br>
                <input type="number" id="txtQtde" min="1" max="5" oninput="calcTotal();">
            </p>
            <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                Adicionar
               <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button> 
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </section>
```

Javascript

```
$(".btGravar").on('click', function(){
    var produto = $('.prod').html();
    var quantidade = document.getElementById("txtQtde").value;
    var orçamento = $('#txtValor').html();
    var valor = orçamento * quantidade;
    var adicionar = '<tr><td>' + produto + '</td><td>' + quantidade +'</td><td>' + valor + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btApagar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Apagar</button></td></tr>';
    $(".tb0").prepend(adicionar);
    $("#shopCart").modal("show");
    }
)
```

Comment: Você tem duas classes com mesmo nome prod

Comment: Conseguiu resolver?

Answer (score 1):

Cara fiz um exemplo pra você, vou resumir tudo o que você precisa pesquisar e pensar antes. Dê uma olhada na documentação que você vai entender tudo o que foi feito.

No HTML:

- Não utilize ID's para mais de um elemento, se você vai ter dois elementos com o mesmo ID isso deveria ser uma CLASSE
- Presta atenção no fechamento de tags ou estrutura incorreta, você tem um

  e um  fundidos, pode estar dando algum conflito.
- Sendo assim, tudo o que era ID duplicado eu utilizei Classes.

No JavaScript:

- No JavaScript, principalmente nos Click Handlers, você tem uma variavel `this`, essa variavel vai indicar qual o elemento que realizou aquele determinado evento. No caso do botão, será o elemento do botão.
- Por esse elemento você consegue encontrar os demais elementos, através de métodos como `.closest()` e `.find()`.
- No meu exemplo, utilizei o botão para encontrar a div pai que tem o ID do produto, e a partir dessa div consegui encontrar os elementos internos que contém os valores, nome e input.

```js
$(".btGravar").on('click', function() {
  var botaoClicado = $(this);
  var produtoClicado = botaoClicado.closest('div');

  var produto = produtoClicado.find('.prod').html();
  var quantidade = produtoClicado.find('.txtQtde').val();
  var orcamento = produtoClicado.find(".txtValor").html();
  var valor = orcamento * quantidade;
  console.log(produto, quantidade, orcamento, valor);
  //     var adicionar = '<tr><td>' + produto + '</td><td>' + quantidade +'</td><td>' + valor + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btApagar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Apagar</button></td></tr>';
  //     $(".tb0").prepend(adicionar);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="Fonte">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="prod">Fonte Corsair 400w</legend>
      <img src="imagens/Fonte/fonte-corsair-vs400-80plus-white-pfc-ativo-400w-cp-9020117-la-1502453690.jpg" id="foto">
      <p>R$:
        <span class="txtValor">229.90</span>
        <p>
          Quantidade
          <br>
          <input type="number" class="txtQtde" min="1" max="5">
        </p>
        <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                            Adicionar
                            <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                        </button>
    </fieldset>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="pv1060">
    <fieldset>
      <legend class="prod">GTX 1060 3GB</legend>
      <img src="imagens/Placa_de_video/placa-de-video-geforce-galax-gtx-1060-oc-3gb-60nnh7dsl9c3-gddr5-pci-exp_33631.jpg" id="foto">
      <p>
        R$
        <span class="txtValor">1349.90</p>
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        Quantidade
                        <br>
                        <input type="number" class="txtQtde" min="1" max="5">
                    </p>
                    <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                        Adicionar
                        <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
                    </button>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Você está com Id's duplicados, não podem existir id's com o mesmo nome referenciando elementos diferentes, para isso você deve usar classe. O código que você está fazendo entende que ele deve buscar um id(que deve ter somente 1 com esse nome), por isso ele só retorna 1 produto, ele acha o primeiro id com o nome que você passou e já retorna.

Answer (score 0):

Como disseram nas outras respostas, não use o mesmo `id` em vários elementos. Troque os:

`id="txtValor"` e `id="txtQtde"`

por

`class="txtValor"` e `class="txtQtde"`

No script você irá pegar esses valores com:

```
var quantidade = $(this).closest("fieldset").find(".txtQtde").val();
var orçamento = $(this).closest("fieldset").find(".txtValor").html();
```

Outro problema está em pegar o preço na variável `orçamento`. Como você está pegando o HTML do elemento, o retorno virá algo como `R$ 229,90`, o que não é um número válido para fazer cálculos.

> A propósito, você está usando duas construções diferentes:

```
<p>R$: </p><p input type="number" id="txtValor">229.90</p>
```

e

```
<p id="txtValor">
   R$ 1349,90
</p>
```

Sugiro que deixe na forma da segunda, até porque a primeira é inválida. Deixe tudo assim:

```
<p id="txtValor">
   R$ 1349,90
</p>
```

Para pegar o preço em forma numérica válida (apenas os números de `R$ 1349,90`), você usa uma expressão regular com `.match()`:

```
orçamento = orçamento.match(/[\d|\,]+/)[0].replace(",", ".");
```

A regex `/[\d|\,]+/` irá pegar somente números e a vírgula, resultando em `1349,90`, mas também é preciso substituir a vírgula por ponto para delimitar as casas decimais, uma vez que o JavaScript considera somente o ponto como delimitador de decimais, por isso o `.replace(",", ".")`.

Feito isso, seu código (pelo menos o mostrado na pergunta) ficará funcional:

```js
function calcTotal(){
}

$(".btGravar").on('click', function(){
    var produto = $('.prod').html();
    var quantidade = $(this).closest("fieldset").find(".txtQtde").val();
    var orçamento = $(this).closest("fieldset").find(".txtValor").html();
    orçamento = orçamento.match(/[\d|\,]+/)[0].replace(",", ".");
    console.log(orçamento);
    var valor = orçamento * quantidade;
    var adicionar = '<tr><td>' + produto + '</td><td>' + quantidade +'</td><td>' + valor + '</td><td><button class="btn btn-danger btApagar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>Apagar</button></td></tr>';
    $(".tb0").prepend(adicionar);
    $("#shopCart").modal("show");
    }
)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<table class="tb0"></table>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Essa class row que é a linha que eu falei-->  
    <div class="row"> 
        <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="Fonte">
            <fieldset>
            <legend class="prod">Fonte Corsair 400w</legend>
                 <img src="imagens/Fonte/fonte-corsair-vs400-80plus-white-pfc-ativo-400w-cp-9020117-la-1502453690.jpg" id="foto">
            <p class="txtValor">R$: 229,90</p>
            <p>
                Quantidade<br>
                <input type="number" class="txtQtde" min="1" max="5" oninput="calcTotal();">
            </p>
            <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                Adicionar
               <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button> 
        </fieldset>
    </div> 
    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3" id="pv1060">
        <fieldset>
            <legend class="prod">GTX 1060 3GB</legend>
                 <img src="imagens/Placa_de_video/placa-de-video-geforce-galax-gtx-1060-oc-3gb-60nnh7dsl9c3-gddr5-pci-exp_33631.jpg" id="foto">
            <p class="txtValor">
               R$ 1349,90
            </p>
            <p>
                Quantidade<br>
                <input type="number" class="txtQtde" min="1" max="5" oninput="calcTotal();">
            </p>
            <button type="add" class="btn btn-primary btGravar">
                Adicionar
               <i class="fas fa-plus"></i>
            </button> 
        </fieldset>
    </div>
    </section>
</div>
```